# c# webbrowser control, navigates on dynamic menu hover?

Tags: c#, browser, webbrowser-control, webresource.axd

I have a form in my winforms app that acts as a built-in browser. It uses the .net webbrowser control. Pretty simple. I have a textbox as an address bar, and buttons for control. When I navigate to my website, my website uses a .net menu control to present a hover menu. When I hover over the menu (using my browser form), the address bar changes to: http://domainname/WebResource.axd?etc/etc/etc, unexpectedly

I am trapping the webbrowser_navigating event and setting the Text property of the address bar to e.Url.ToString()

Of course, this is not the expected result, and IE doesn't do this. 
What am I missing?

UPDATE:

Here's the only way I could come up with how to do this:

```
                string url = e.Url.ToString().ToLower();

                // Only change the address bar under certain circumstances
                // Filter out some navigating changes
                if ((StringUtil.Empty(e.TargetFrameName) || e.TargetFrameName.ToLower() == "_blank") &&
                    !url.Contains("webresource.axd") &&
                    !url.Contains("javascript:") &&
                    !url.Contains("about:blank"))
                {
                    toolStripAddress.Text = e.Url.ToString();
                }
```

Comment: what is the (javascript?) code that pops the menu in the page?

Comment: Some code will make things more clearer.

Comment: Don't know, didn't write it :-) It is using a standard .NET menu control built into .NET version 3.1SP1.

Comment: the .net or js  code that pops the menu in the page is clearly triggering this Navigating event. Maybe it is changing the text on the page and calling the 'DocumentText' method. You may need to check WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs.TargetFrameName or Url properties to filter it out.

Comment: Yes, I already checked the e.TargetFrameName property, and it is blank. However, is there not a more unhackish way of doing this other than checking the Url property and manually filtering out WebResource changes? I.E. if it does it with my website, what will it do when the user browses to another website that uses ajax type technology that is not on a .NET platform?

Comment: Filtering out WebResource.axd changes fixed the immediate problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Sanjay's comment above.